# Python subprocess.Popen: redirection with ">" does not work

Tags: python, bash, process

The following code does not work properly in Python. The problem is that the output does not get redirected to `output` by using `>`:

```
command = toolpath + " " + query + " " + number + " > " + output;
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE);
output = process.communicate()[0];
```

The command is actually the following if you print it:

```
./subsetA.pl ./remainingqueries.fasta 100 > ./tmpQuery.fasta
```

So the perl script `subsetA.pl` takes two arguments and writes it to `stdout` which gets redirected to `tmpQuery.fasta`. But `tmpQuery.fasta` is empty after the command gets called.

If I run it direct on CLI then it works perfectly.

Comment: did you try it with `shell=True` in Popen?

Comment: Now it the perl script does not get arguments :-(

Comment: ah, yes, you don't need split any more

Comment: et voilà... thanks! thats it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
command = toolpath + " " + query + " " + number + " > " + output;
process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,Shell=True);
output = process.communicate()[0];
```

Comment: Now the perl script does not get the arguments :-(

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the shell's output redirection operator with `Popen`; that's what the `stdout` argument is for.

```
command = [toolpath, query, number]
with open(output) as output_fh:
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=output_fh)
```

Since you are calling `communicate` to get the standard output, though, you don't want to redirect the output at all:

```
command = [toolpath, query, number]
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = process.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. How do I write the output to a file?

Comment: That's what the first command does. You open the file in Python, and pass the `file` object to `Popen` to let it set standard output for the child process.

Answer (score 0):

Both current answers don't work!

This works (tested on Python 3.7):

```
subprocess.Popen(['./my_script.sh arg1 arg2 > "output.txt"'],
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Note:

1. You do not need split or array in Popen.
2. BOTH `stdout` and `shell` parameters are needed.